# Is it possible to integrate RabbitVCS to Caja file manager?

Tags: python, mate, rabbitvcs, version-control, caja

It is known that RabbitVCS may be integrated into Nautilus file manager by installing the corresponding [`rabbitvcs-nautilus` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=rabbitvcs-nautilus).
This adds related menu items calling tools for Subversion (SVN) and Git.

But is it possible to integrate it into Caja file manager as in Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS or 18.04 LTS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @DKBose with his finding - we need to use RabbitVCS script from https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/tree/master/clients/caja .

But with small correction - we can not use latest (*master*) version.

- For 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS we need to run the following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt install rabbitvcs-cli python-caja python-tk git mercurial subversion

  mkdir -p ~/.local/share/caja-python/extensions
  cd ~/.local/share/caja-python/extensions
  wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/v0.16/clients/caja/RabbitVCS.py
  caja -q
  caja
  ```
- For 20.04 LTS:

  ```
  sudo apt install rabbitvcs-cli python3-caja python3-tk git mercurial subversion

  mkdir -p ~/.local/share/caja-python/extensions
  cd ~/.local/share/caja-python/extensions
  wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/v0.18/clients/caja/RabbitVCS.py
  caja -q
  caja
  ```

and enjoy:

[image: RabbitVCS on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS]