# How to enable default file manager(nautilus) to handle desktop icons

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, desktop-icons

How can I allow nautilus to draw desktop icons in 20.04? I made `org.gnome.desktop.background.draw background= true` but nothing happened.
Before I made it done by enabling `org.gnome.nautilus.desktop.show desktop` to true. But now, even the schema is not available  now.

What's wrong with it?  Is I'm only able to make desktop icons with an extension only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already know - it is impossible, the functionality [was removed](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/files-nautilus-v3-28-will-lose-the-desktop-icons-capability/3115?u=norbert) from Nautilus.
By such actions GNOME developers do not respect user habits, so it is time for taking action by us, the users.

You have to install MATE DE with Caja (fork of Nautilus) by

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

then select MATE session in login screen and enjoy.

The below screenshot demonstrated all features of normal desktop integration between file-manager and desktop:

> [image: Fully-featured MATE desktop controlled by Caja]

Here we have Mutiny panel layout and the following elements arranged by user:

- home folder icon;
- link to Dropbox folder (the folder itself is located in `~/Dropbox`, controlled by `caja-dropbox` extension);
- desktop shortcut to Caja application copied from menu;
- pdf file with preview;
- simple text file;
- folder with Git repository inside (controlled by [RabbitVCS extension](https://askubuntu.com/a/1149104/66509));
- folder with Mercurial repository inside (controlled by [TortoiseHG extension](https://askubuntu.com/a/1229850/66509));
- simple folder with opened dropdown menu which demonstrates custom actions and menus from various extensions including custom caja scripts (usually located in `~/.config/caja/scripts`) and actions configured using `caja-actions-config-tool`.

The screenshot of dropdown menu for empty desktop space is below:

> [image: dropdown menu alone above MATE desktop controlled by Caja]

Note: above screenshots may be overloaded by the stuff, but they demonstrate how flexible MATE desktop is nowadays. You can compare them with default GNOME Shell and GNOME FlashBack to make conclusions by yourself.

Comment: It's a nice replacement  for the boring gnome desktop environment. As you said, new version of gnome is a complete clean-up of new features. I don't know why they removed them,  including the basic utilities.

Comment: It's not necessary to replace the desktop. [Sami's comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/+bug/1868924/comments/4) has worked very well for months on several machines: delete `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano`; install package `nemo`; and create a .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart pointing to `nemo-desktop`

Comment: @bitinerant it is a hack, hacks are not welcomed by new normal regular users. So the avoidance of new GNOME ideas is better idea.

Comment: @N0rbert I disagree that this is a "hack". It's simple and has worked well for me. The procedure described above involves installing 338 additional packages and using 962 MB of disk space. Let the users decide.