# Unable to right-click and add the "workspaces selector" in GNOME classic's taskbar of my ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mouse, gnome-classic, taskbar

I would like to add the "workspaces switcher" in GNOME classic's taskbar of my ubuntu 20.04.
The right-click of the mouse has no response.

I've installed the gnome-tweak-tool, and the "mouse & touchpad" page in it has nothing to do with that.
Could anyone please help me?

Comment: IMHO it is time to switch to Ubuntu MATE. Here you can do more. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1263992/66509) for details. About customization [see guide](https://guide.ubuntu-mate.org/#personalization-panel-layouts). Workspace switcher on MATE allows at least window move between workspaces by mouse.

Comment: @N0rbert Wow! Ubuntu MATE is really what I need! I was a CentOS user and more familiar with GNOME2 than GNOME3. I just realized that MATE is the continuation of GNOME2!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO it is time to switch to Ubuntu MATE. Here you can do more. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1263992/66509) for details. About customization [see guide](https://guide.ubuntu-mate.org/#personalization-panel-layouts).
Workspace switcher on MATE allows at least window move between workspaces by mouse:

[image: Workspaces on MATE]

To start using Ubuntu MATE on top of existing desktop you need to install it by

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

then reboot and select MATE session on login screen.